# How to find coordinates of tangent point on circle, given center coordinates, radius, and end point of tangent line

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

I'm working on a hobby programming project and my mathematic thinking is feeling a bit slow at the moment. Basically, in situations similar to the image I made, given the information I mentioned in the title, I need to be able to calculate the coordinates of the tangent point. (Dimensions are from the origin.) Could you all help me out with finding a straightforward way of doing so? Thanks in advance.
[image]

(P.S. In the program, this will actually be in 3D, but once I have the 2D solution I should be able to figure it out in 3D.)

Comment: Hey. You can start by finding the angles that the hypotenuse of the triangle makes with X axis, after that find the length of the hypotenuse to find the angle of the radius that it makes with X axis. Finally once you get the slope you can solve for the equation of radius. Solve the simultaneous equations of circle  as well as the radius to get the common point. Note that the intersection will have x coordinate as -ve and y coordinate as +ve.

Comment: Thanks for the input Snehil. Also, thanks for editing my post to have the image in the post body instead of just a link to it. I tried to do that myself at first but with it being my first post on math.stackexchange it told me I didn't have enough reputation to do that yet lol.

Comment: Hey Steven. It might be intimidating in the beginning but then you will really enjoy. The community is great and people are really helpful. Feel free to explore :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not actually need trigonometry. Let $AC = r$ be the radius, let point $A$ be at $(x_1, y_1)$, and point $B$ be at $(x_2, y_2)$. You know the values of $r, x_2$, and $y_2$.

First find the length of $AB$ using Pythagoras. Then using the distance formula (Pythagoras again) and squaring both sides, $(y_2 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - x_1)^2 = AB^2$.

In addition, $(x_1, y_1)$ must lie on the circle, so $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = r^2$. Solving these two equations will give you $x_1, y_1$ in terms of the other variables. There will be two solutions, but you can plot each of them and determine which one is correct for the general setup.

Comment: Thank you. I'm marking this as correct since it is a more complete answer, though I will probably still use the more trigonometric method for my specific use case.

Comment: No problem! I'm impressed that you've managed to create your own solution based on the other answer.

Comment: Well I've worked on a good number of similar calculations; I was just a bit slow at figuring out this one lol.

Comment: One additional thing for future readers, it might be good to note that your x and y variables use the circle's center as the origin.

Answer (score 3):

The point at which the tangent line touches the circle (call it $A$), the endpoint of the tangent line (call it $B$), and the center of the circle (call it $C$) form a right triangle. We know the radius of the circle (length of $AC$) and the distance from the center of the circle to the endpoint of the tangent line (length of $BC$).

All that remains is to use the Pythagorean theorem and a bit of trigonometry to find the length of the remaining side, as well as the angle between the remaining side ($AB$) and side $BC$. That should be enough information to find the coordinates of point $A$.

Comment: Actually, I was already aware of how to get the lengths of the sides and internal angles of the triangle. I just wasn't sure how to use those to get the coordinates of that specific point. Now that I think about it a little more, I suppose once I do so I could also calculate the angle of BC with the x axis, and then use this along with the angle between AC and BC to get the angle of AC and the x axis, and then use trig to find the point coordinates from there. I'm not sure if there's a more direct way though.

Comment: That also works. Once you find the angle $\theta$ from the $x$-axis (counterclockwise), the coordinate of $A$ is just $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ from the unit circle definition. All of these ways are pretty direct so you can choose whichever one you like.

Comment: Thanks Toby, that's true. Robert, this is probably the method I will go with; it's just missing that final step I mentioned in my last comment. Thanks for the answer though, it helped me to rethink the problem and find a solution for that step.

Comment: @StevenLightning You're certainly welcome! I should've included more details than just "a bit of trigonometry," but I'm glad you were able to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

The following includes all.

$$ \text{ Power=} T^2, \; C^2 = T^2 +R^2 =  h^2+k^2$$

$$ \tan \gamma =\dfrac{R}{T};\tan \beta =\dfrac{k}{h} $$

$$  \text{Tangent points  } [\;T  \cos (\beta \pm \gamma), T \sin (\beta \pm \gamma)\;] $$

$$(h,k)= (-30, -70).$$

[image]

Without Trigonometry  the formulas for tangent point coordinates plug-in and calculations are:

$$\boxed{ \dfrac{hT\mp kR}{C},\dfrac{kT\pm hR }{C}}$$